# Angular 6 Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object of type 'string'

Tags: json, angular6

As you can see by the subject, I am receiving this error because one of the columns in the database is a string of JSON and I thought I could get around this by having an ngFor loop within an ngFor loop.

The following is the html:

```
 <tbody>
  <tr *ngFor="let item of mf.data">
    <td>{{ item.id }}</td>
    <td>{{ item.user_id }}</td>
    <td class="text-right">{{ item.orders_id }}</td>
    <td>
      <ul *ngFor="let x of item.product">
        <li>{{ x.name }}</li>
        <li>{{ x.price }}</li>
        <li>{{ x.category }}</li>
        <li>{{ x.ts }}</li>
        <li>{{ x.enabled }}</li>
        <li>{{ x.counter }}</li>
      </ul>
    </td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

The following is what one row of the column "product"  looks like:

```
 [
  {
    "id": "13",
    "name": "test 5",
    "price": "3.42",
    "category": "chocolates",
    "ts": "2019-01-08 10:41:15",
    "product_image_id": "50",
    "enabled": "1",
    "product_image": "40-64-grand-canyon.png",
    "counter": "2"
  },
  {
    "id": "18",
    "name": "test 4 post dubs",
    "price": "6.72",
    "category": "chocolates",
    "ts": "2019-01-08 08:55:49",
    "product_image_id": "36",
    "enabled": "1",
    "product_image": "first-ent-rent-ridgegate.png",
    "counter": "3"
  },
  {
    "id": "9",
    "name": "something test 3 upd",
    "price": "12.23",
    "category": "chocolates",
    "ts": "2019-01-08 08:54:49",
    "product_image_id": "29",
    "enabled": "1",
    "product_image": "80-44-grand-canyon.png",
    "counter": "2"
  }
]
```

BTW, I have tried the following, with no errors, but nothing displays as well:

```
 <tbody>
  <tr *ngFor="let item of mf.data">
    <td>{{ item.id }}</td>
    <td>{{ item.user_id }}</td>
    <td class="text-right">{{ item.orders_id }}</td>
    <td>
      <ul *ngFor="let x of mf.data.product">
        <li>{{ x.name }}</li>
        <li>{{ x.price }}</li>
        <li>{{ x.category }}</li>
        <li>{{ x.ts }}</li>
        <li>{{ x.enabled }}</li>
        <li>{{ x.counter }}</li>
      </ul>
    </td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

Along with trying the following, but errors of product not being defined:

```
<tbody>
  <tr *ngFor="let item of mf.data">
    <td>{{ item.id }}</td>
    <td>{{ item.user_id }}</td>
    <td class="text-right">{{ item.orders_id }}</td>
    <td>
      <ul *ngFor="let x of mf.data[i].product; let i = index">
        <li>{{ x.name }}</li>
        <li>{{ x.price }}</li>
        <li>{{ x.category }}</li>
        <li>{{ x.ts }}</li>
        <li>{{ x.enabled }}</li>
        <li>{{ x.counter }}</li>
      </ul>
    </td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because of `product` object which is not converted into JSON along with other given data as it is nested object.

In your **template**, call the method to convert **`product`** string to **JSON object**

```
<ul *ngFor="let x of convertToJSON(item.product)">
```

Create a method in your **component** like below

```
convertToJSON(product: any) {
    return JSON.parse(product);
}
```

Comment: thank you for replying and thank you for the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

change your code like this.

```
 <tbody>
      <tr *ngFor="let item of mf.data">
        <td>{{ item.id }}</td>
        <td>{{ item.user_id }}</td>
        <td class="text-right">{{ item.orders_id }}</td>
        <td>
          <ul *ngFor="let x of item">
            <li>{{ x.name }}</li>
            <li>{{ x.price }}</li>
            <li>{{ x.category }}</li>
            <li>{{ x.ts }}</li>
            <li>{{ x.enabled }}</li>
            <li>{{ x.counter }}</li>
          </ul>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
```

Use ***ngFor="let x of item"** insted of *ngFor="let x of item.product"

Comment: thank you for replying. When I try what you have suggested, I receive the following error - Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.