# Cannot access child interface data from API in angular. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: json, angular, interface

New to Angular 7 here and need some help. So I have a JSON stream that looks like this:

```
{
    "Id": 25,
    "Name": "XYZ Corp",
    "CompanyAddresses": [
        {
            "Id": 39,
            "CompanyId": 25,
            "Address1": "998 Roosevelt Court",
            ...
        }
    ]
}
```

company.ts & companyaddress.ts: I created two interfaces in Angular like so:

```
import { CompanyAddresses } from './company-address';
export interface Company {
    Id: number;
    Name: string;
    CompanyAddress: CompanyAddress[];
}
export interface CompanyAddress {
    Id: number;
    CompanyId: number;
    Address1: string;
}
```

company.service.ts: I then use a service to fill the interfaces like so:

```
  getCompany(id): Observable<Company> {
    return this.http.get<Company>(this.baseUrl + 'company/' + id, httpOptions);
  }
```

company.component.ts: And then call the service in my component:

```
  company: Company;
  constructor(private companyService: CompanyService) {}
  ngOnInit() {
    this.activatedRoute.data.subscribe(data => {
      this.company = data['company'];
    });
  }
```

Now here is my problem. When in my component's HTML, I can access the company name with {{company.Name}} but if I try to access any of the data inside of CompanyAddress like so {{company.CompanyAddress.Address1}}, there is no way to do so. The properties don't exist.

Do I need to initialize the CompanyAddress interface at some point before I dump the JSON data into the Company interface?

Is there a better method to accomplish what I am trying to do? Maybe something that will make it easy to save changes back with a PUT in the same format? What is considered best practice?

Edit: HTML Template Code Added

```
<div><h3>{{company.Name}}</h3>
<p>
    <div *ngFor="let addy of company.CompanyAddress">
        {{addy.Address1}}
    </div>
</p>    
</div>
```

I should also mention that I am using Visual Studio Code and it does not show any properties inside of CompanyAddress.

Here is the ASP.Net Core 2.1 controller code:

```
[Authorize]
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class CompanyController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet("{id}")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Company(int id)
    {
        var company = await _repo.GetCompany(id);
        var companyToReturn = _mapper.Map<CompanyForContactDto>(company);
        return Ok(companyToReturn);
    }
}
```

According to Postman, everything checks out.

Comment: Please add your template code.

Comment: Please add your template the code and the value of the `this.company` object.

Comment: `company.CompanyAddress.Address1`, in this, company address is an array right so shouldn't you access it like company.CompanyAddress[index].Address1 ?

Comment: @emkay I gave that a shot using {{CompanyAddress[1].Address1}}. Unfortunately, no data was returned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@ThaKidd KG5ORD, give a try to this

I think your **`JSON object`** is fine for the `first interface` but in the case of `child interface` data it is not converting to `JSON object`. Maybe it is still a string so, do some changes like below

> add a method in **Component.ts**

```
ConvertToJSON(product: any) {
    return JSON.parse(product);
}
```

> **component.html**

```
<div *ngFor="let addy of ConvertToJSON(company.CompanyAddress)">
        {{addy.Address1}}
</div>
```

I have answered similar kind of [question here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54176120/9764133) check it once.

Comment: Unfortunately, this did not fix the problem. Stupid side question...is there a way to evaluate what data is in the Company interface?

Comment: Actually just noticed that I am getting this in my browser: ERROR SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1 at JSON.parse (<anonymous>). Not sure what that means but will Google it.

Comment: @ThaKidd KG5ORD, we need to convert array to JSON object so, try this change in the ConvertToJSON() method  `JSON.parse` to `JSON.stringify`

Comment: Changed to stringify. Now I get this Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object [{"Id":22,"CompanyId":24,"Address1":"898 Greene...

Answer (score 1):

Everything is looking fine in your service side and component side. I think you are getting that error because when you navigate to your (template) page, you are trying to render `company` variable before your service response.

And my prediction is that you are not using `*ngIf` clause on you template side,

**For example,**

```
<div *ngIf="emp1">
  Id:{{emp1.id}} Name: {{emp1.name}}
</div>
<div *ngIf="emp2">
  Id:{{emp2.id}} Name: {{emp2.name}}
</div>
```

I've replied similar SO question tomorrow, please [check it](http://stackoverflow.com/a/55038536/5955138).
Hope it helps.

**UPDATE:**

Please try this,

```
<div *ngIf="company && company.CompanyAddress">
 <h3>{{company.Name}}</h3>
  <p>
    <div *ngFor="let addy of company.CompanyAddress">
        {{addy.Address1}}
    </div>
  </p>    
</div>
```

Comment: Are you saying that no data has loaded yet and that is why nothing is happening? I get the company name back. The other weird thing is Visual Code's intellisense doesn't see the CompanyAddress.properties either.

Comment: @ThaKiddKG5ORD Yes, that is what I actually thinking about. Can you please add *ngIf notation on your template? By the way im double checking classes that you used.

Comment: I added the *ngIf statement you recommended. Nothing loads. If I remove the company.CompanyAddress from ngIf, everything loads except for the address block (ngFor).

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out! The problem was solved by adding the following on top of the ASP.Net Core API controller: **[Produces("application/json")]**

```
[Authorize]
[Produces("application/json")]
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class CompanyController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet("{id}")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Company(int id)
    {
        var company = await _repo.GetCompany(id);
        var companyToReturn = _mapper.Map<CompanyForContactDto>(company);
        return Ok(companyToReturn);
    }
}
```

After doing that, I changed my HTML component back to the following:

```
<div><h3>{{company.Name}}</h3>
<p>
    <div *ngFor="let addy of company.CompanyAddress">
        {{addy.Address1}}
    </div>
</p>    
</div>
```

Thanks to all for putting me on the right track of a bad Json Get.
This also started working after the change:

```
{{company.CompanyAddress[1].Address1}}
```

Comment: Nice, but you still need to use *ngIf notation :D Otherwise you will face with differend issues, good luck.